# How to convert date into specific date format

Tags: javascript, date

I am having date which is in mm/yyyy format. I need to compare this date with today's date. I have converted today's date.

After converting I have got date in mm/dd/yyyy format..But I need to covert it into mm/yyyy format..So that I can compare this date into, date which I am getting..Any help please.

```
selecteddate=05/2019  //which is in mm/yyyy format

myDate= new Date().toLocaleDateString(); //which is in mm/dd/yyyy format( I need to convert this date into mm/yyyy format and need to compare with selecteddate)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`toLocaleDateString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) options

```js
let date = new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-US', {year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit' })

console.log(date)
```

Comment: This will work...Thank yo so much

Comment: @RobG My fault, Check updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps,

```js
const date = new Date();
const myDate = `${(date.getMonth() + 1)}/${date.getFullYear()}`;
console.log(myDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), as follows:

```js
moment().format('MM/YYYY')
```

Comment: Moment is a very heavy package so there are other alternative ones. For example, date-fns. You can see a brief comparison in the repository: https://github.com/you-dont-need/You-Dont-Need-Momentjs

Comment: moment is easier to use in comparison to other libraries available @AlexeyKorkoza but in the all upto you what you want to use

Comment: I agree with you that the package is easy-to-use but you should think about performance and the size of your bundle as well.

Comment: I agree with you that it's heavy,I tried to use date-fns I felt it was complicated so I choose to stay with moment @AlexeyKorkoza

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
selecteddate='05/2019'
selecteddate= datetime.datetime.strptime(selecteddate, '%m/%Y')
today_dtime= datetime.datetime.now()
today_dtime.date()>selecteddate.date()
```

output:True
One thing note down month and year will assign as in selecteddate,But date will be 1st of respected month.
try this simple trick

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following logic to compare your selected date with today's date

```js
const selectedDate="05/2019"; // MM/YYYY
const today = new Date();
const todayString = `${(today.getMonth() + 1)}/${today.getFullYear()}`;
const matched = ( todayString === todayString );
console.log("Does your selected date matched with today's date ?",(matched ? "Matched":"Don't Matched"));
```

Comment: This won't work reliably as it doesn't pad single digit months, so in May will compare "05/202" with "5/2020". Also `( todayString === todayString )` will always return true (and the brackets are redundant).

Comment: Thanks, @RobG , to bring my attendance to that area.